# Map data from from one JSON schema to another as they share common data in php

Tags: php, json, jsonschema, data-mapping

I have product data from our internal system that has a particular JSON schema. I have to transform/map it into another json schema format so that this new data can be pushed to another system. I am aware of manually going through each data and creating new data. Is there any library that takes data that belongs to one JSON schema and based on mapping/rule supplied to it converts into another format?

Comment: Off-topipc: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: So far I am just decoding the json string that belongs to one schema into another by manually checking which field can be mapped to the other. So what I am suggesting is a library in php , I am aware that there is https://github.com/dvdln/jsonpath-object-transform#jsonpath-object-transform for node.js that exactly does what I am looking for.

Comment: I could not find any library which I could give the schema and I could get all the properties that belongs to certain property in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This library could help: https://github.com/ScriptFUSION/Mapper

> Mapper transforms arrays from one format to another using an object composition DSL. An application often receives data from a foreign source structured differently than it wants. We can use Mapper to transform foreign data into a more suitable format for our application using a Mapping as shown in the following example.